# How to maintain list order in Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am making my first postgres app with react. It's a simple todo list.

Right now when you retrieve the list of tasks you get the following:

```
pernstack=# SELECT * FROM todo;
 todo_id |          description
---------+-------------------------------
     825 | First task
     826 | Second Task
     824 | Third task
     822 | Fourth task
(4 rows)
```

The problem is if I edit the first task with a `PUT` request. That task gets put to the bottom of the list. Here is the edit request:

```
app.put("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const updateTodo = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE todo SET description = $1 WHERE todo_id = $2",
      [description, id]
    );

    res.json("Todo was updated");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

What is the most basic way to edit the task without moving it out of order? I didn't want to havet to manually add an `index` column. In MySQL I believe this is done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY todo_id` will make them always be in the order they were added, assuming `todo_id` is an auto-incremented number

If you want to be able to specify the order of the list in the future, you would want to add a column labeled `list_order` or something like that, then do `SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY list_order`

Comment: Thanks, obvious answer I guess but I wanted to make sure there wasn't an automatic way this was done in Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Database tables are unordered sets. Unless you explicitly use an `order by` clause when querying the table (e.g., with a manual `task_index` column, like you suggested), you can not assume anything about the order returned from a query.